# Adjust design of algorithm when using the algorithmic package

Tags: algorithmic

I am using overleaf and I have inserted an algorithm into an template for a conference. Unfortunately, the algorithm is not displayed in the way I like:
-the caption should be above the steps
-there should be two lines before the caption "Algorithm" above 
- there should be a line at the end of the algorithm

Basically it should look similar to this examples (line numbers are not necessary):
https://math-linux.com/latex-26/faq/latex-faq/article/how-to-write-algorithm-and-pseudocode-in-latex-usepackage-algorithm-usepackage-algorithmic

I tried to do this like they did, but it did not work out and I had to use the "algorithmic" \usepackage{algorithmic}

I'd appreciate every comment. Thanks for your help in advance.

EDIT: Here is the Latex Code

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[options ]{algorithm2e}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}

\title{Title \\
{\footnotesize \textsuperscript{}}
}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{} \\
\textit{}\\
\\
}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{} \\
\textit{}\\
 \\
}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{} \\
\textit{}\\
 \\
}

}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Abstract
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
component, formatting, style, styling, insert
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction}


\section{Optimization Problem}



\section{Methodology}
\label{section: Methodology}


\subsection{Method 1}




\begin{algorithm}[h]
\SetAlgoLined
 \While{$t < Z$}{
  \If{$T^{min} \leq T_t^{BS} \leq T^{max}$}{
   Set $x_t = x_t^S$\;
   }
   \If{$T_t^{BS} > T^{max}$}{
   Set $x_t = mDeg^{min}$\;
   }
   \If{$T_t^{BS} < T^{min}$}{
   Set $x_t = 1$ \;
   }
   Set $t=t+1$\;
 }
 \caption{Algorithm 1}
  \label{algo:BS}
\end{algorithm}


\subsection{Method 2}





\bibliography{bibtex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Here overleaf support is off-topic. Moreover, please do not add links in the question (they'll be dead soon) instead add a MWE that explains your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I added the Latex code. 
Looking forward for your answers